# Android rendarscript on video

Tags: android, video, renderscript

Renderscript is new for me and i want to know that can i use renderscript for apply filter or effect on video. I know that renderscript is best option for image processing.
Can any one suggest me how we apply video effect and filter on my project.

Comment: what about modifying the shown frame?

Comment: I want to apply video effect like instagram.

Comment: so you want to create a new video file from the original with shiny effects on it?

Comment: can you help me for this?

Comment: sorry I don't know how this kind of programs work.